# Proof that two classes multiplied with each other form a complete class

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Consider a group $\mathcal{G}$ having two of its classes $C_i=\{A_1,A_2,A_3 ... A_m \}$ and $C_j=\{B_1,B_2.B_3...B_n\}$ having $m$ and $n$ elements each.
We are supposed to prove that the product of these two classes forms a complete class. The book that I am reading this from- "Elements of Group Theory for Physicists by AW Joshi" gives the following proof.

> $$C_iC_j=\{A_1B_1,A_1B_2...A_1B_n,...A_mB_n\}$$
> It would be enough to prove that any element $A_lB_k \in C_iC_j$ has a corresponding conjugate element present in $C_iC_j$.
> Thus, let $A_lB_k \in C_iC_j$. Consider an element $X$ in $\mathcal G$.
> $$X^{-1}A_lB_kX=(X^{-1}A_lX)(X^{-1}B_kX)=A_rB_s\ \text{(say)}$$
> But by definition of a class, $A_r \in C_i$ and $B_s\in C_j$. This completes our proof.

I have problems with the last line. How do we know that $(A_l,A_r)$ and $(B_k,B_s)$ are conjugates with respect to the same element $X\in \mathcal G?$

My guess is that conjugation of two elements of a group is true irrespective of what we choose $X$ as. Is that correct? Is that nonsense? Is the proof wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Note that in the first part of the question, you say "class", whereas in the second part, you say "complete class". If this terminology is from the book, it may be useful to figure out what the distinction is between these, as that may explain the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a class is meant to be a conjugacy class then this is not true in general: for a counterexample take $G=S_3$ and multiply the conjugacy class $\{(123),(132)\}$ by itself, yielding the subgroup $A_3$, which is not a conjugacy class.  Call a subset $S$ of a group $G$ *normal* if $g^{-1}Sg \subseteq S$ for all $g \in G$. Conjugacy classes and normal subgroups are examples of normal subsets, as well as complements of normal subgroups. It is easy to show that a normal subset is the (necessarily disjoint) union of certain conjugacy classes. Now, if $S,T$ are normal subsets, then also their product $ST$ is normal: $g^{-1}STg=g^{-1}Sg \cdot g^{-1}Tg \subseteq ST$, since both $S$ and $T$ are normal.

Comment: This means that the above proof is incorrect right?

Comment: Yes it is, unfortunately